WSLにてcrontabコマンド を使いたいいが、rootはダメですとシステムから返答。
WSLにて crontab -e, crontab -l を使いたいが、rootはダメですとシステムから返答。
わたしの実行環境:
# uname -a Linux HL 5.15.153.1-microsoft-standard-WSL2 #1 SMP Fri Mar 29 23:14:13 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

crontab -e にて emacs か vim で以下書き込み
***** touch /tmp/sss

企図:
例題としてファイル名sss にタッチして推移をみる
画面エラーメッセージ:
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) y
crontab: installing new crontab
new crontab file is missing newline before EOF, can't install.
Do you want to retry the same edit? (y/n) n
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.uHuNHh/crontab
root@HL:/mnt/g/マイドライブ# crontab -l
no crontab for root


sudo は使えませんか? まずは、sudo -s としてrootになれるかどうか確認してみてください

「rootはダメです」という独自の表現ではなく、実際に表示されたメッセージをそのまま質問に含めてください。

質問者です。上記のようにcrontab- l コマンドに対しては無反応で企図としてはファイルの推移が反映されるようなのですが、エラーではないのですか？操作間違い？

メッセージ内容の方向性が逆では？「rootはダメです」ではなく「root用のcrontabがない」では無いですか？ /etc/cron.dへ置くファイルにはownerとpermissionに制約があるっぽい それと置き場所が違うのでは？ crontabの書き方や確認、仕組みや落とし穴を理解する


new crontab file is missing newline before EOF, can't install.

これが最も重要なメッセージです。crontab -e の編集結果の最後に改行コードがないため受け付けられないと言ってます。改行を足してエディタを抜けてください。
